# Error installing @angular/cli

Tags: windows-10, command-line, node.js

I am having an issue when I try to install Angular CLI.
When I write this command on the cmd prompt on Windows 10:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\munoz_ps>npm install -g @angular/cli
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:18420) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I'm using the following environment

```
Node: 12.9.0
NPM: 6.11.1
OS: MS Windows 10.0.17763.678
```

[Printscreen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aHyl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a known issue and a release with fix is awaiting
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29239